# How to get specific data from Realtime Database in flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter

> I have fetched the snapshot values named as name and role and I store
> them as userName and user role.
> I want to access the same data in the same widget but it cannot recognize. Please help

[image: Image file]

Comment: In line number 38, to use your variable username you should write '$username' to get the value of the variable username. This is the correct way to access a variable value inside a Text widget.

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare (and initialize `userName` and `userRole` variables if you are using newer versions of dart) before the Widget. Something like:

```dart
String userName = "", userRole = "";
```

or

```dart
late String userName, userRole;
```